# Disable mailboxes on Exchange 2007 while emails are being redirected to Gmail

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2007

I am trying to uninstall Exchange 2007 for a client as they have decided to use Gmail from now on.
I have been going through some errors like the transport connector and the watermark and now I am hitting another wall. I got these errors:

> "Error: Uninstall cannot continue. Database 'Mailbox Database': This
>   mailbox database contains one or more mailboxes. To get a list of all
>   mailboxes in this database, run the command Get-Mailbox -Database
>   . To disable a mailbox so that you can delete the mailbox
>   database, run the command Disable-Mailbox  Recommended
>   Action:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=30939&l=en&v=ExBPA.12&id=4a96fd69-9cec-4a48-9571-5c9e8ab3cfe9
>
> Error: Uninstall cannot continue. Database 'Public Folder Database':
>   The public folder database "GLFP01\Second Storage Group\Public Folder
>   Database" contains the following offline address book(s): \Default
>   Offline Address Book . Before deleting the public folder database,
>   move the offline address book(s) to a web-based distribution point.
>   Recommended Action:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=30939&l=en&v=ExBPA.12&id=b6e3b32a-8848-46cb-9567-72288ac15f60
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:09
>
> Client Access Role Prerequisites Completed
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:02
>
> Hub Transport Role Prerequisites Completed
>
> Warning: There are 1 messages waiting in the 'GLFP01\Unreachable'
>   queue. Proceeding with the removal of the server role may result in
>   data loss."

My concern is if I disable the mailboxes, the emails that are being forwarded to Gmail might not reach their owners?

Comment: How exactly are the emails being forwarded to Gmail?

Comment: I updated your question, if I missed the intent of the question please revert the edit.